# Largest independent sets in triangle free graphs-question about an equality

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, ramsey-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a triangle free graph of order $N$ and for $x\in V$, let $D(x)$ be the the set of neighbours of $x$, and $G_x$ be the induced subgraph of $G$ on the subset $V\setminus \{x\}\cup D(x)$. Also, let $\beta(G)$ be the size of the largest independent set of $G$, then according to this [notes](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Edconlon/RamseyLecture3.pdf) (end of the first page)
$$
\beta(G) = 1+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{x\in V}\beta(G_x).
$$
I could not prove the statement. Can someone explain why this equality will be true? (some hints/steps/reference will be very helpful)

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the formula, but isn't this false for a path graph of $5$ vertices? Largest independent set would have $3$ vertices but right hand side gives me $1+8/5$. If I'm not misreading it, maybe it was meant to be a $\geq$ instead of a $=$?

Comment: You are right, probably this was a typo in the notes. Do you know a proof if equality is replaced by $\geq$? That will be sufficient as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, think that the independent set of $G$ has to be of the form of $\{x\}$ joined with the largest independent set of $G_x$ for any $x$ in the maximal independent set. In particular, it's the maximum of $1+\beta(G_x)$ for all $x$. The maximum must be greater or equal than the average, which gives the inequality.

Comment: @AnilCh Thanks, your proof is clear. I did not realize that the "triangle-free"  is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the hints.
If $M$ is a maximal independent set in $G_x$,
then $M\cup\{x\}$ is an independent set in G.
Therefore $\beta(G)\geq\beta(G_x)+1$.
It follows that
$$
\beta(G)\geq\frac{\sum_{x \in V} \beta(G_x)}{N}+1.
$$
The converse inequality is wrong, as @AnilCh rightly pointed out.

Comment: Why is $\beta(G) = |M| \leq \beta(G_x) + 1$? Take a path graph of five vertices as a counterexample.

Comment: @AnilCh, yes, you are right. I have edited my post.